# Sum elements in matrix in Excel

Tags: excel

```
id  a   b   c

1   0   0   0
1   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
2   0   0   0
3   1   2   3
3   0   0   1
```

Given the above matrix, I want to create a new matrix, which sums the numbers within the first matrix for a given id in a given year (a,b or c). So for the above, it should look like:

```
    1   2   3
a   0   0   1
b   0   0   2
c   0   0   4
```

Can anyone see what to do?

Comment: have you considered using an IF statement (I'm a bit rusty on my excel, but I think there's an ADDIF or COUNTIF, or maybe VLOOKUP) that would do what you want. Just use IF != 0 and sum.

Comment: I have tried SUMIFS(sumrange, criteriarange1, criteria1, ...) In relation to the upper matrix in my question above I make a new matrix that looks like the lower one in my question and type the following formula in the first element of the lower matrix: 
=SUMIFS(B2:D7,B1:D1,a,A2:A7,1)
The problem may be that sumrange has to be single column or row, but I don't know how to get around that problem in my case.

Comment: have you got a reason not to use a pivot table ? Seems ideal for that !

Comment: I have no reason not to use a pivot table other than I do not have any experience using Pivot tables and it does not seem to work by just marking the table area and clicking the Pivot table button. But I will have a look into that.

Comment: i agree, @idevlop if you believe that pivot tables are the solution please provide your method

Answer (score 2):

Try using SUMPRODUCT rather than SUMIFS, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:D7,(B1:D1="a")*(A2:A7=1))`

Comment: +1  - the way to go. Finally simpler than a Pivot in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The formula solution given in the other responses will work well when data headings are already in place and the data range is not too large.

A pivot table creates the row and column headings for you and will update as new data is added when you click the Refresh Button, it's also significantly quicker when the data range is large.

[image]

**Steps**

A) Choose `Insert | Table` for your data range, and give it a suitable name, the default is *Table1*

B) Access the PivotTable wizard via the shortcut `Alt+D+P` (this is not on the default menus).

```
1)  Multiple Consolidation Ranges 
2a) I will Create the Page Fields
2b) Range: Table1[#All]  Page Fields: 0
2c) Existing Worksheet: $A$7
```

C) Click Finish, switch Row and column fields and turn off totals and autoformatting

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you try solving that problem with pivot tables.
Here are 2 links that you might use to learn that feature:
http://www.cpearson.com/excel/pivots.htm
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7zHLnUCtfUk

The only drawback with Pivots is that if the size of the source range changes, the Pivot will not adjust automatically. So once you managed to solve your initial problem and understand the power of Pivot Tables, I suggest that you use a [Dynamic Named Range](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/excelF.htm#DynamicRanges) as the source of your Pivot.

---

Edit:
I feel that [barry houdini's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11004602/78522) is simpler. I reproduced it below (with all credit belonging to him!)
[image]